# Putting json content into PHP variable

Tags: php, json

I need to manipulate some data which is being given to me in json format, from which I need to extract some data and put into a variable in PHP.

Having tried my best, I seem to end up with errors such as :

```
Use of undefined constant collectionViewUrl - assumed 'collectionViewUrl'
```

At the moment the only real code I have is this:

```
$string = file_get_contents("https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=rihanna+diamonds&country=gb&media=music&entity=musicTrack&attribute=musicTrackTerm&limit=1");
$json_result = json_decode($string, true);
```

I do not need an array of any kind, I just need to put the value of **collectionViewUrl** into a variable.

Comment: Somewhere you are referencing `$collectionViewUrl` without the `$` sign

Comment: @robbmj is correct. Post the code where you reference `collectionViewUrl`.

Comment: This is what I was using 
echo $json_result[collectionViewUrl];

Comment: The problem was that `collectionViewUrl` was not quoted `$json_result["collectionViewUrl"];` also you were not looking in the correct array as noted in @Khaled Bentoumi answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here how to get the collectionViewUrl string into a variable

```
$string = file_get_contents("https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=rihanna+diamonds&country=gb&media=music&entity=musicTrack&attribute=musicTrackTerm&limit=1");
$json_result = json_decode($string, true);
$collectionViewUrl = $json_result['results'][0]['collectionViewUrl'];
```

Here is a codepad where you can try the code http://codepad.org/6Zogs3si

**Explanation :**

When the 2nd parameter of `json_decode` is set to true the function return an associative array who's really close to the structure of the JSON.

From there all what you got to do is put back the JSON path into an associative php array to access the wanted value !

Comment: This works, many thanks for your assistance. marked as answer

Comment: @omega1 you're welcome happy to help, could you check it as answered so that it could help futur user ? Thanks